# How to programmatically stop a simulation run in an optimization experiment?

Tags: anylogic

I have 20 equipment units. And they all fail after a storm. I will send several service crews to repair them. I want to see the impact of the number of service crews on total restoration cost(which is roughly estimated = cost of repair of units+number of service crews *cost of crew per day * time()+number of failed equipment*revenue per day *time(); here time() gives the number of model time units(days) from zero until the experiment stops). If I increase the number of service crews, the time to repair those 20 units will be decreased. I want to minimize the total cost. So, I want to put stop conditions other than time because time varies for different crew sizes. Is there a way that I can stop the experiment run after 20 equipment units are repaired?

I found that we can end the use '**Never stop**' option in the model time section, and terminate the run using a condition. I tried to add additional stop conditions, but it did not work. Where should I write the stop condition?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzHSq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are specifying when the entire optimization should stop.

What you *think* you are doing is to define when a single run should stop.

You can do this from within the model. For example have a cyclic event that checks if your condition is met. Or implement the check directly where your repair counter is updated.

You simply kill your single run then by using `stopSimulation()`. This kills a single run, and the optimization can continue with the next run